# Компилятор не находит шаблон для специализации

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct box
{
    char maker[40];
    float height;
    float width;
    float length;
    float volume;
};
template <typename T> T biggest(const T a,const T b);
template <> double biggest(const box a,const box b);//вот здесь проблема
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    box a {"HELLO MOTHERFUCKER!!!", 0, 0, 0, 4.4};
    box b {"HELLO !!!", 0, 0, 0, 4.5};
    cout << biggest(100,105) << endl;
    cout << biggest(a,b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
/*Функция biggest просто возвращает наибольшее из переданных ей значений*/
template <typename T> T biggest(const T a,const T b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    if (a < b)
        return b;
    else 
        return 0;
}
/* А здесь функция biggest возвращает наибольшее из переданных ей структур значение volume*/
template <> double biggest(const box a,const box b)//вот здесь проблема
{
    if (a.volume > b.volume)
        return a.volume;
    else if (a.volume < b.volume)
        return b.volume;
    else 
        return 0.0;
}
```

[Ссылка на онлайн компилятор с кодом](https://rextester.com/ZVNFPQ73173)

Похоже, проблема в `template <> double biggest(const box a,const box b);`,компилятор не находит шаблона для этой специализации. Разве это из-за разных возвращаемых значений специализации и ее шаблона? Почему происходит ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Специализация шаблона - это вариант, когда вместо параметра шаблона используется что-то более конкретное. Если в специализации для `T biggest(const T a, const T b)` заменить `T` на `double`, получится `double biggest(const double a, const double b)`, или на `box`, получится `box biggest(const box a, const box b)`. Очивидно, что `double biggest(const box a,const box b)` не получится ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Чтобы возвращаемый тип мог отличаться от типов параметров, он должен быть сделан отдельным параметром шаблона:

```
template <typename x_Input, typename x_Result = x_Input>
x_Result biggest(const x_Input a,const x_Input b)
```

тогда специализация будет

```
template <>
double biggest<box, double>(const box a,const box b)
```

при этом для вызова этой специализации необходимо будет явно указывать первый и второй параметры, так как тип возвращаемого значения в шаблонах не выводится
`biggest<box, double>(a,b)`

Также вместо специализации можно сделать отдельную нешаблонную перегрузку `double biggest(const box a,const box b)` - ее можно вызывать как `biggest(a,b)`, так как она более приоритетная по сравнению с шаблоном.