# Шаблоны и перегрузка функций

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Задали в нашем великолепном вузе задание: Описать функцию, находящую площадь кольца, заключенного
между двумя окружностями с общим центром и радиусами R1 и R2. R1, R2
могут быть int или float.
Решил вот так: `

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double pi = 3.14;

template <class type>
type overload(type parab, type parbb)
{
    static int result;
    result = (pi * pow(par1, 2)) - (pi * pow(par2, 2));
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    int ri1 = 10, ri2 = 7;
    float rf1 = 4.5, rf2 = 3.5;
    cout << overload(ri1, ri2) << endl;
    cout << overload(ri1, rf1) << endl;
    cout << overload(rf1, ri2) << endl;
    cout << overload(rf1, rf2) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

`
Когда вывожу функцию с разными параметрами, float и int или наоборот, сообщает что в шаблоне отсутствуют необходимые экземпляры, подскажите в чем тут проблема?

Comment: У вас в шаблоне написано, что оба аргумента имеют один и тот же тип `type`.

Comment: То есть нужно описывать 2 шаблона?

Comment: Если типы аргументов должна отличаться, то и параметров шаблона должно быть больше - по одному на каждый аргумент. Плюс еще наверное нужен параметр для типа возвращаемого значения. Похожий вопрос:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250396/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/1250406#1250406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше решение бессмысленно, потому что множить, например, на `pi` и выдавать значение `int` - странно, не находите?

Решить ваши затруднения можно так:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
std::common_type_t<T,U> overload(T a, U b)
{
    using R = std::common_type_t<T,U>;
    return R(pi) * (a*a-b*b);
}
```

Т.е. просто все приводить к одному типу, результирующему типу для арифметических операторов.

Правда, не вижу большого смысла в таком решении, если `pi` у вас задано безусловно, как `double`, а для `int` станет тройкой... (Кстати, 3.14 - это что за приближение? хотя бы 3.1415926535898)

Поэтому реально я бы предложил работать просто с `double` - и неважно, какие типы на входе :)

```
double overload(double a, double b)
{
    return pi*(a*a-b*b);
}
```

И последнее - судя по названию, может, вам для препода нужен не шаблон, а перегрузка? Определите две функции с разными параметрами - для `float`, для `int` (с другим "пи" :))...

Ну, а шаблонное решение представлено выше.

Comment: Задание было с перегрузкой. Но для себя было интересно написать шаблон. Спасибо за решение.